# Not able to call a function within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I am making a Toss Simulator.
This is my code:

```
import random

class TossSimulator():

    heads = 0
    tails = 0

    def doFlip(self):
        x = random.randint(0,1)
        if(x == 0):
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def getScore(self, flip_function):
        if flip_function is True:
            self.heads+=1
        else:
            self.tails+=1   

obj = TossSimulator()

obj.getScore(doFlip())
```

The error I am recieving is :

> NameError : name 'doFlip' is not defined at line 24

Comment: `doFlip` *isn't* defined at the scope where you called it; it's a method of the `TossSimulator` class.

Comment: You should call this way: `obj.getScore(obj.doFlip())`

Comment: @chepner oh ok, I edited my code by writing `obj.doFlip()` and works.

Comment: `doFlip` doesn't use an instance of `TossSimulator`, so it should be defined as a regular function outside the class.

Comment: btw, if you can simplify your `doFlip` function to simply `return random.randint(0,1) == 0`

Comment: Your parameter name for `getScore` is misleading; you aren't passing a function as an argument, but a Boolean value.

Comment: @chepner yes, I want to have a boolean as a parameter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, I will simplify it thanks.

Comment: Also, I would just not use classes right now, if you are beginning. A class doesn't add anything here. Plus, it looks to me like you are using some tutorial where the tutor is familiar with Java, and teaching you that, but the semantics of Java and Python are different with respect to class definitions. Note, if you *did* want to make a class, you should make an `__init__` method and not rely on class variables.

Comment: If the provided answer helped you, please mark it as correct so that people who come across your question in the future know what worked.

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need a class for this, but if you just want to practice, then practice well! The problem is, as stated in the comments, that `doFlip` does not exist in the scope in which you are trying to call it. Wrapping some of the comments up into a solution that illustrates some nice features:

```
import random

class TossSimulator():
    def __init__(self, flip_function):
        """
        Args:
        flip_function: function that returns True (heads) or False (tails)
        """
        self.heads = 0
        self.tails = 0
        self.flip = flip_function

    def get_score(self):
        if self.flip():  # call stored flip function
            self.heads += 1
        else:
            self.tails += 1
        print('Heads: {}\tTails: {}'.format(self.heads, self.tails))

def do_flip():
    return random.randint(0, 1) == 0  # skip the middle man

obj = TossSimulator(do_flip)
obj.get_score()  # prints the running total heads and tails
# Heads: 0        Tails: 1
```

A couple of important changes were made. First, I added the `__init__` function, which is the constructor for Python objects. This is where you want to define any of your member variables, initialize things, etc. With the class defined this way, you can make multiple instances of your `TossSimulator` and they will each keep a record of their own scores:

```
obj1 = TossSimulator(do_flip)
obj2 = TossSimulator(do_flip)
obj1.getScore()  # Heads: 1        Tails: 0
obj1.getScore()  # Heads: 1        Tails: 1
obj2.getScore()  # Heads: 0        Tails: 1  (scored separately)
obj2.getScore()  # Heads: 0        Tails: 2
```

Second, I made `flip_function` a parameter that is passed to your constructor. Now you can define a special flip function for each instance of your `TossSimulator` when you create it, and then `get_score` will use the flip function defined *for that instance* every time you call it:

```
def always_heads():
    return True

obj1 = TossSimulator(do_flip)
obj2 = TossSimulator(always_heads)
obj1.getScore()  # Heads: 0        Tails: 1
obj1.getScore()  # Heads: 1        Tails: 1  (random flips)
obj2.getScore()  # Heads: 1        Tails: 0
obj2.getScore()  # Heads: 2        Tails: 0  (always will be heads)
```

Third, I cleaned a couple of things up. You can, for instance, replace something like this:

```
if x == y:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

with `return x == y`. They're exactly the same, but one is much more concise (and possibly very slightly more efficient?). You can also directly check the "truthiness" of a function's return, so you do not need to use `if self.flip() == True:`; you can just use `if self.flip():`.

You can take that last point a step further and directly check the "truthiness" of a numeric value. In Python, zero is `False` and all other integers are `True`. [A summary of what values are true and what values are false can be found here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html).